# Como mostrar valores ao invés de porcentagens no gráfico de pizza do matplotlib?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['ALAGOAS','BAHIA','CEARÁ','MARANHÃO','PARAÍBA','PERNAMBUCO','PIAUI','RIO GRANDE DO NORTE','SERGIPE']
precos = [7.127,7.703,7.587,7.135,7.092,7.164,8.105,7.576,7.370]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

ax.pie(precos, labels=labels, autopct='%.3f', shadow=True)
ax.set_title('Preços medio da gasolina por estados', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Antes de usar o site faça o [tour]. Também leia [ask], saiba que [nossas publicações são formatadas com Markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) e para mais orientações sobre o uso do site veja [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e [help]. Também não deixe de ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101)

Answer (score -1):

No [gráfico de pizza](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html) para a cada fatia mostrar seu respectivo valor ao invés de mostrar porcentagem, quando exibido a porcentagem é valor padrão da fatia, atribua a propriedade `autopct` uma função que transforme uma porcentagem no seu respectivo valor nominal:

```
  f(porcentagem) = Total_da_amostra * porcentagem / 100
```

ou

```
  lambda v:f"R${sum(precos)*v/100:.3f}
```

Onde:

- `Total_da_amostra = sum(precos)`
- `v=porcentagem`

Veja o exemplo

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['ALAGOAS','BAHIA','CEARÁ','MARANHÃO','PARAÍBA','PERNAMBUCO','PIAUI','RIO GRANDE DO NORTE','SERGIPE']
precos = [7.127,7.703,7.587,7.135,7.092,7.164,8.105,7.576,7.370]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

ax.pie(precos, labels=labels, autopct=lambda v:f"R${sum(precos)*v/100:.3f}", shadow=True)
ax.set_title('Preços medio da gasolina por estados', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image: Gráfico do preço da gasolina nos estados brasileiros 28/05/2022]

<sup>Tese o exemplo no [COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Rpww-VeSjwZFpZtGPCsX_lQtJv-mjp_B?usp=sharing)</sup>

Comment: Se possível, quem votou negativo deixe uma orientação identificando os problemas com a resposta.